# How to write a simple scope for a Unity lens?

Tags: unity, lenses, scopes

I am looking for a tutorial on writing a scope for simple search from a website. [The tutorial at Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses) is very complex.

If somebody can explain me the steps to write a scope in a simplest way, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

There is a full-blown tutorial and scopes here:

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorial/

There are some good examples of stand-alone scopes here: https://code.launchpad.net/onehundredscopes

Comment: I've put together a python script, only I've got one problem: How do I actually **use** it?