# how to add sources in video lenses?

Tags: unity, search, source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a simple scope for a Unity lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107317/how-to-write-a-simple-scope-for-a-unity-lens)

Im pretty new to ubuntu and was attracted to the idea on 12.04 of the video lenses where to searches BBC iPlayer etc for videos yet in the 'sources' tab i only seem to have 'my videos' as the source. Any help with how to add BBC iPlayer etc..?

Comment: This requires programming, see link above.

Comment: He isn't asking how to write a scope, but why a source is missing from the scope. The video scope used to include videos from BBC iPlayer, now it doesn't - his question is why and how can he add it. Indeed it seems like there is no control over the video scope at all any more. Is it abandoned like the social scope?